# Recalling a NSNumber on valueforkey

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnumber

Im am trying to display a `NSNumber` in my detail view of my application using core data. Currently I can get it working with a string value however I am stumped when trying to recall a nsnumber. I get a [__NSCFNumber length] error which I understand to be because I need to convert the nsnumber to a string? How would I go about changing the following code to do so? `weightkg` is the entity attribute containing the `nsnumber`.

```
   [self.kgLabel setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"weightkg"]];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have little control over formatting if you just use `stringValue` for your `NSNumber`. Instead you should make sure to convert into the correct primitive data type and format as desired:

```
kgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f kg", number.floatValue];
// --> "23 kg"

kgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f kg", number.floatValue];
// --> "23.43 kg"
```

Comment: interesting. How would I incorporate this with valueForKey:@"weightkg"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.kgLabel setText:[[self.device valueForKey:@"weightkg"] stringValue]];
```

Comment: brillant. and fast response! Ill accept when it lets me (10 mins). Out of interest why does adding stringValue fix it?

Comment: The UILabel text property accepts an NSString. The method stringValue converts the NSNumber to an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.kgLabel setText:[[self.device valueForKey:@"weighting"] stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
[self.kgLabel setText:[[self.device valueForKey:@"weightkg"]] stringValue];
```

**Update:** I'll throw in another one:

```
[self.kgLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ kg" [self.device valueForKey:@"weightkg"]];
```

This way you'll get more.